# Срабатывания функции когда елемент в зоне видимости окна

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.animate_self').hide();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var fullWidth = $('#pg1Overlay').offset().left;
    var elemThis = $('.animate_self').offset().left;
    if(fullWidth > elemThis - 300){
        $('.animate_self').show(1000);
    }
    return false;
})
```

Вот скрипт который я написал. У меня есть на странице определённая высота. При этом горизонтальный паралакс.  Поэтому и беру .offset().left от #pg1Overlay. Сейчас скрипт работает. Но не так как я хочу. Мне надо что бы каждый элемент у которого такой класс появлялся по отдельности. Сейчас все элементы у которых этот класс появляются синхронно. Помогите решить трабл. Буду очень признателен.

[Сыылка на сайт](http://cleancode.me/test/supra_final/)

Comment: Добавьте html и css этой части, что бы проще было решить проблему

Comment: http://cleancode.me/test/supra_final/ - вот ссылка на сайт, так как кода очень много его валидатор не пропускает.

Comment: У меня ноут и телефон не вывозят прогрузки 

Comment: Если можно напишите как это решить, может через data атрибут, или же каким-то другим способом. Просто надо реализовать логику  - что бы скрипт обрабатывал элеметны не все сразу а по очереди.